Cannot get prebuilt apk to update in AOSP build
I am trying to add a prebuilt apk to my android AOSP and have been successful at adding it. I have now updated the app and would like it to be updated in the Android image. I did so by updating the .apk file in my AOSP build directory. I cannot get the AOSP image to use the updated .apk file. I have tried:

make clean-my-app
deleted the out directory
make clobber
updated version code of the app

I am unsure of why or where from the build system is getting the old apk from.
The app i am trying to build into the img is a system app installed in /system/priv-app/my-app/my-app.apk. Its built using flutter
--Update--


Need to see your Android.bp or Android.mk file.

I have added my Android.mk file which adds my app

Did you add the line PRODUCT_PACKAGES += ui-flutter to your device mk file? For example if you want to add your package to the emulator you would put that line in https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:device/generic/goldfish/product/generic.mk

Yes, that has been added in another makefile. The app gets built into the image. Its just that I cannot get it to update if I replace the apk with a new one
